# Best way to find if path exists in a unidirectional directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph with huge number of nodes with one start node ( all edges are outward ) and one end node ( all edges towards it ). It is an unidirectional and unweighted graph.How to optimize the search in this kind of graph for finding out if path exists between two nodes ? I know BFS provides a solution. Is there anyway to optimize the search ( like adding some additional information ) as I will be doing frequent search on the graph?

EDIT : To add more information about the graph, the graph has one start node with multiple out-edges and one end node with multiple in-edges. In between, there are millions of nodes connected. It is an unweighted DAG. And there are no heuristics involved. Just check isConnected(node a,node b).

Comment: @santosh.ankr It is acyclic.

Comment: Are you familiar with A* search?

Comment: @templatetypedef I suppose in case of unweighted edges, A* is similar to DFS.

Comment: It's actually closer to BFS than DFS. Do you have a heuristic function you can use?

Comment: @templatetypedef I have no heuristics. Just wanted to check if two nodes are connected. Since there are million nodes, I need something better than BFS. I can add some info on the nodes if needed.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about where this graph comes from, what the nodes and edges mean, etc.? Without any more data, I doubt we can provide any suggestions better than BFS.

Comment: In order to let others help you with this problem, you should probably update your question to include more information about the graph. Asking about this in chat isn't likely to help you get an answer. If you can't post that information for some reason, you may need to delete the question, since it's too vague to get a good answer.

Comment: If you're doing this kind of query very often, then you may want to use Dijkstra's algorithm (if the source is always the same) or [Johnson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) (if the source varies).

Comment: @user1429322 - are you sure you don't have a potential heuristic? IIRC A* doesn't require your nodes to have a position in a road-map style Euclidian space - it only requires a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). Of course plenty of graphs don't have any such heuristic available as they're not associated with anything you could call a space, but I thought it was worth double checking.

Comment: WRT larsmans suggestion, Dijkstra is a priority-order search which visits the vertices nearest to the starting vertex (by number of edges distance) first. One alternative, even if you can't use A*, is to have a priority-order search that expands outwards from both the start and end points until a vertex is encountered in both searches - expanding out from both points until you meet in the middle. You can imagine this as two circles expanding until they collide - the sum of the areas will be less that for one circle expanding around the start until it hits the end.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your graph is acyclic  here is a way to do it : -

> 1. Do DFS on graph start with source vertex(only outgoiong edges)
> 2. For each edge (u,v) in the graph connected[u][v] = true
> 3. Try to store the previous node in DFS stack in a array & for each vertex v visited check the previous nodes in the stack and do
>      connected[u][v] = true where u is a previous node.

If graph is not acyclic then first calculate SCC's using Kosaraju or Tarjan and then reduce the graph to acyclic and do connected[u][v] = true for each pair in a SCC

pseudo code for modified DFS routine:-

```
bool connected[n][n] = {false};   
bool visited[n] = {false};   
int stack[n]; 

for each source vertex v do :   
     DFS(v,stack,0);


void DFS(int u,int stack[n],int depth) {


    if(!visited[v]) {

          visited[v] = true;

          for(int i=0;i<depth;i++) {

               connected[stack[i]][v] = true; 
          }

          stack[depth] = u;

          for each edge(u,v) {
             connected[u][v] = true;
             DFS(v,stack,depth+1);
          }
    }
}
```

Space Complexity : `O(V^2)`

Time Complexity : `O(V^2)`

**Note:-**

If your number of queries are less then try to use DFS for them individually and cache the results as this will be more time consuming then that.